# How to package a single-file Windows EXE for downloading?

Tags: .net, windows, installation, download

I have a freeware program to ready share via my website.  It consists of a single Win32 executable file.  Its only external dependency is the .NET 4.0 client framework.  The EXE file is digitally signed with my authenticode signature.

How should I package it for distribution from my website, and why?

- post the raw EXE file?
- post a ZIP file, containing the single EXE?
- produce an actual installer (MSI) to post?
- or?

Comment: If you create an installer, please make sure it works without administrative permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are intending to target only Windows it's probably best to create an MSI file. You can create one by adding a Setup project to your solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: This has the advantage of letting the installer ensure that .NET 4.0 is installed, and if not, install it.

Answer (score 2):

Post the EXE file.

As a user, I would find it more convenient to know what I am downloading and don't have to guess for example say if it was zipped.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) installer that installs the program, creates a start menu and/or desktop shortcut, and [checks](http://tonaday.blogspot.com/2010/12/innosetup.html) for .NET and downloads+installs if needed.  Also sign the installer.  It's dead easy to create the installer, and this will make your program more widely accessible.

Comment: Why do you say "more widely accessible"?  Also, what's the advantage of Inno Setup vs. a VS Setup project?

Comment: You don't have to depend on the user making sure .NET is properly installed or figure out how to unzip a file, and the shortcut makes it easier for the user to find your program in the future.  In my experience, Inno Setup is a lot easier to work with than VS Setup projects.  Also, despite Windows Installer being the MS-sanctioned installer format, I've found Inno installers to be less error-prone on the average end user PC (no annoying 'installing...' popups like you often see when launching Office apps, etc.).